# Trouble including function declaration for strptime()

Tags: c

Have a time date string I'd like to convert to a tm object.  Google tells me the POSIX (but not the C) standard includes a function called `strptime()` that will do the job.

The man page says it's in `<time.h>` and that I need to include `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE` before I include the `<time.h>` file.  Easy enough.

But I still get an implicit declaration warning from the compiler.  I opened `/usr/include/time.h` and found the function declaration:

```
 # ifdef __USE_XOPEN
/* Parse S according to FORMAT and store binary time information in TP.
   The return value is a pointer to the first unparsed character in S.  */
extern char *strptime (const char *__restrict __s,
               const char *__restrict __fmt, struct tm *__tp)
     __THROW;
#endif
```

So it looks like I need `#define _USE_XOPEN` instead.

Except that doesn't work either.  The compiler still isn't seeing the declaration.

Any ideas.  I'm using a relatively recent version of Linux (Mint) with gcc 5.4.0.

Comment: Options include using `-std=gnu11` instead of `-std=c11`  on the GCC command line, or using `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` or equivalent.  700 identifies POSIX 2008; 600 or 500 identify earlier versions of POSIX or X/Open.

Comment: Thanks John, but neither of those suggestions seem to do the trick.  I have trouble seeing how the compiler doesn't see the declaration, since I checked and it is indeed in the time.h file.

Comment: `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` / `#include <time.h>` / `#include <stdio.h>` / `int main(void) { printf("%p\n", (void *)strptime); return 0; }` — that doesn't compile for you as `gcc -std=c11 -Wall -c test-strptime.c`?  If you add `-ansi` to that, you reset the standard back to C90.  GCC 5.4.0 should default to C11 (effectively `-std=gnu11`) unless someone did something horrible in the build you're using (which is unlikely).

Comment: Your first bit of code did compile.  Interestingly however, it doesn't if I put #include stdio.h before the #define.  So I think its the order of the include statements relative to the definition that's causing the trouble.  I'll play with it some more in my code and report back.

Comment: The `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` must precede the first system header (whether included directly or indirectly).

Comment: That was it, thanks.  I obviously need to go learn more about how test macros work.

Comment: Another option is to download a public domain implementation of `strptime` and add to your project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<sup>*Converting comments into an answer.*</sup>

To fix this, your options include using `-std=gnu11` instead of `-std=c11` on the GCC command line, or using `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` or equivalent (e.g. `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700` on the command line). The 700 identifies POSIX 2008; 600 or 500 identify earlier versions of POSIX or X/Open.

In theory, you could also use `_POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` (see POSIX [Compilation environment](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02)), but that doesn't expose everything that `_XOPEN_SOURCE 700` exposes so it is usually better to use the latter.

Note that the POSIX specification of [`strptime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html) is annotated as an XSI extension, which means you must set `_XOPEN_SOURCE`; setting `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` alone is not sufficient.

#### Test code

This test code prints the address of the `strptime` function; it won't compile if `strptime()` is not declared.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%p\n", (void *)strptime);
    return 0;
}
```

That should compile for you with `gcc -std=c11 -Wall -c test-strptime.c`. If you add `-ansi` to the options, you reset the standard back to C90. GCC 5.4.0 should default to C11 (effectively `-std=gnu11`) unless someone did something horrible in the build of GCC that you're using (which is unlikely).

Note that the compiler unsets and then sets `__USE_XOPEN` based on settings like `_XOPEN_SOURCE` and trying to set it manually doesn't work reliably.

#### Position matters

You must specify the `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` before the first system header is included (whether included directly or indirectly). If you include a system header before trying to set `_XOPEN_SOURCE`, the settings have been determined and your subsequent operations are effectively ignored.  POSIX says (at the 'compilation environment' link already given):

> In the compilation of an application that `#define`s a feature test macro specified by POSIX.1-2008, no header defined by POSIX.1-2008 shall be included prior to the definition of the feature test macro. This restriction also applies to any implementation-provided header in which these feature test macros are used. If the definition of the macro does not precede the `#include`, the result is undefined.

One common undefined result is that your attempt to set/change the POSIX version is completely ignored.

Comment: Is it meant to work to use different source defines for different units in the same build, or should they all be the same?

Comment: @M.M: you're into 'unspecified behaviour', I think.  Generally, you'll get away with it because the standard (POSIX or C) interfaces don't evolve — once they're standardized, they remain fixed until they're removed from the standard.  Even then, they may continue to exist long after they're no longer standard (`gets()` anyone?).  With functions such as `strptime()` or `strftime()`, the direct C interface doesn't change, but the set of format options that are accepted does.  This afflicts C and `printf()` too.